error al usar EXCEP en comaparación de 2 consultas en access
necesito comparar el resultado de 2 query, para ver posibles diferencias
al ejecutar la siguiente sentencia me da error:
"error de sintaxis en la cláusula FROM"
ESTA ES LA QUERY:
SELECT [Concatenación], Macroservicio FROM [01 - Inclusión Macroservicio]
EXCEPT
SELECT Concatenacion, Macroservicio FROM 01_Inclusion_Macroservicio;
LA primera tabla lleva nombre de tabla con espacis en blanco y corchete y y la columna lleva tilde es por eso que van encerrada en corchetes. y de esa forma se diferencia de la otra consulta, pero ambas consultas tienen el mismo tipo de dato
